# Can I evaluate a clojure file in boot?

Tags: clojure, boot

So, in Debian:

```
$ cat file.clj
(println "Hello")

$ ls clojure-1.7.0.jar 
clojure-1.7.0.jar

$ java -cp clojure-1.7.0.jar clojure.main -i file.clj
Hello
```

How do I do this with `boot`?

Without modifying `file.clj`, or setting up extra project files, or any other form of pointless ceremony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
boot -f file.clj
```

Comment: Indeed it does! Thank you very much I was looking for that for hours